# Execute large scripts without increasing allowed memory in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management, pdo, phalcon

I am trying to make a Cron Job background process which generates stuff for each registered user in the database.

Now, I'm trying to get a MySQL table with essential settings for the process. I want to get the whole thing at one because it contains settings for all the users involved in the process. Also the site has over 250K users so looping the process for each user (get separate user data 250K times) would be a performance killer.

I am using PDO and retrieving data rows by `fetch()` in 50K row pages using `LIMIT`. I get this error

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

whenever I try to save the row data to an array and the script memory limit ~134Mb gets exceeded.
Everybody suggests to increase allowed memory limit to a higher number by using `ini_set()` but that fixes only the symptoms of a bigger problem imo.

Theoretically - What if in some time registered user count raises to such a number that the server memory isn't capable of supporting my running script and a chunk of simultaneous user connections?

That's why I would like to execute my script in the allowed memory limit. **The execution time is not a factor**, it will be executed only once per month or so. Also it's a background process so no response timeouts to worry about.

What about creating a temporary file for all the settings to relieve some of the memory?

Any more ideas?

Comment: what happens when you read 20k row pages using `LIMIT`? if you provide some more information about your script would help to provide some suggestions.

Comment: 20K row page returns those rows. I have 50K row page to minimize outgoing query count.

Comment: You have a barrel full of water and a glass that can hold 0.2 L of water. How  would you use this small glass to transfer water from barrel to somewhere else? Figure the analogy out and that's your solution.